# Unknown Column error executing left join

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to get a left join to work and have an error that says
Unknown column 'sales_order_grid.entity_id' in 'on clause

However I don't know how to re-word the query the column sales_order_grid does contain a column named entity_id? I am trying to run a query that shows results even if the sales_order_tax table has no matching row I want the rest of the data from the other tables to show.

```
SELECT sales_order_grid.entity_id, sales_order_grid.created_at, sales_order_grid.increment_id AS OrderID, sales_order_grid.status, sales_order_grid.payment_method AS payment_method, sales_order_grid.base_grand_total AS pmt, sales_order_grid.base_grand_total AS charged, t.code AS tax_code, t.title AS taxrate, t.amount AS taxamount, 
      sales_order_grid.shipping_and_handling AS shipping_invoice, sales_order_grid.grand_total AS total_invoice, customer_address_entity.firstname, customer_address_entity.lastname, 
      customer_address_entity.city, customer_address_entity.region, customer_address_entity.postcode 
FROM sales_order_grid, customer_address_entity LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_order_tax AS t on sales_order_grid.entity_id = t.order_id
WHERE sales_order_grid.created_at >= '2018-02-01 00:00:00' 
  AND sales_order_grid.created_at <= '2018-02-05 23:59:59' 
  AND sales_order_grid.status IN('Paid','complete','closed','Processing','on hold') 
  AND sales_order_grid.customer_id = customer_address_entity.parent_id    
GROUP BY sales_order_grid.entity_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up 2 different ways in joining your tables.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT sales_order_grid.entity_id, sales_order_grid.created_at, sales_order_grid.increment_id AS OrderID, sales_order_grid.status, sales_order_grid.payment_method AS payment_method, sales_order_grid.base_grand_total AS pmt, sales_order_grid.base_grand_total AS charged, t.code AS tax_code, t.title AS taxrate, t.amount AS taxamount, 
  sales_order_grid.shipping_and_handling AS shipping_invoice, sales_order_grid.grand_total AS total_invoice, customer_address_entity.firstname, customer_address_entity.lastname, 
  customer_address_entity.city, customer_address_entity.region, customer_address_entity.postcode 
  FROM sales_order_grid
  JOIN customer_address_entity on sales_order_grid.customer_id = customer_address_entity.parent_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN sales_order_tax AS t on sales_order_grid.entity_id = t.order_id
  WHERE sales_order_grid.created_at >= '2018-02-01 00:00:00' AND sales_order_grid.created_at <= '2018-02-05 23:59:59'  
  AND sales_order_grid.status IN('Paid','complete','closed','Processing','on hold')  GROUP BY sales_order_grid.entity_id
```

Comment: @Jayreis & isaace The problem is that comma has lower precedence than keyword joins. "Mixing up 2 different ways in joining" is not the problem. *Wrongly* mixing up 2 different ways in joining is the problem.